# LazyInitializationException in Hibernate Reactive with Quarkus (Panache)

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache, hibernate-reactive

I have three entities: Interview, Question and Answer. Interview can have many Questions (and vice versa, many-to-many), Question can have many Answers (one-to-many).

I persist and fetch entities in the following manner:

```html
@ApplicationScoped
internal class InterviewRepository : PanacheRepository<Interview> {
    fun persistInterview(interview: Interview): Uni<Interview> {
        return Panache.withTransaction {
            persist(interview)
        }
    }

    fun getInterview(interviewId: Long): Uni<Interview> {
        return findById(interviewId)
    }
}
// same repos for Question and Answer
```

All persistence operations work fine, interviews and questions are created fine and then both fetched fine as well. But when I create Answer (also fine) and then try to findById Question or Interview entities I get the following error (this one for getting Question):

```
"org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: HR000056: Collection cannot be initialized: com.my.company.question.Question.answers - Fetch the collection using 'Mutiny.fetch', 'Stage.fetch', or 'fetch join' in HQL"
```

It used to show the same error for findById (interview), but FetchMode.JOIN solved the issue. For some reason FetchMode.JOIN is ignored for fetching answer (?).
Instead of using findById I also tried manually writing HQL using left join fetch, but got the same result. What am I missing here?

Interview Entity:

```html
@Entity(name = "interview")
@RegisterForReflection
internal data class Interview (
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    val interviewId: Long? = null,

    @Column(name = "client_id", nullable = false)
    val clientId: Long = Long.MIN_VALUE,

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "interviews", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    val questions: MutableSet<Question> = mutableSetOf(),
)
```

Question Entity:

```html
@Entity(name = "question")
@RegisterForReflection
internal data class Question (
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        val questionId: Long? = null,

        @Column(name = "client_id", nullable = true)
        val clientId: Long? = null,

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @OnDelete(action = CASCADE)
        @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
        val answers: MutableSet<Answer> = mutableSetOf(),

        @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(
                name = INTERVIEW_QUESTION_TABLE,
                joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "question_id", referencedColumnName = "id")],
                inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "interview_id", referencedColumnName = "id")]
        )
        @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
        @JsonIgnore
        val interviews: MutableList<Interview> = mutableListOf(),
)
```

Answer Entity:

```html
@Entity(name = "answer")
@RegisterForReflection
internal data class Answer (
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    val answerId: Long? = null,

    @Column(name = "question_id", nullable = false)
    val questionId: Long = Long.MIN_VALUE,

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(
        name="question_id",
        foreignKey = ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT),
        nullable = false,
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false,
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    val question: Question = Question(),
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Hibernate Reactive, [lazy collections must be fetched explicitly](https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/1.1/reference/html_single/#_fetching_lazy_associations). If yo you try to access a lazy association without fetching it first, you will see that error.

Here's how you can fetch an association with Panache:

```java
import org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.Mutiny;

    fun getInterview(interviewId: Long): Uni<Interview> {
        return findById(interviewId)
            .call(interview -> Mutiny.fetch(interview.questions))
    }
```

Note that fetching associations this way will cause an extra query to the database. Depending on the use case, it might be more efficient to load the association eagerly with a join fetch in a query. This should also work:

```java
    fun getInterview(interviewId: Long): Uni<Interview> {
        return find("from Interview i left join fetch i.questions where i.id = :id", Parameters.with("id", interviewId))
    }
```

In this case, Hibernate Reactive will load everything with a single query.

Also, when using Hibernate, [the developer is responsible to keep bidirectional associations in sync on both sides](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional).

Comment: I tried both options you've suggested, but it's getting the same error as soon as Interview has got some related Questions (i.e. before I insert a question it works fine, but after insertion and fetch again - throws the error above). I created a demo on my GitHub, please take a look if possible (I've put a readme with how-to reproduce): https://github.com/DnEgorWeb/ogram-interviews

Comment: Thanks for the reproducer. That's really helpful. But can you create a test case that I can run, please? I'm not familiar with postman and it would take some time for me to figure out how to reproduce the error. A sequence a curl requests to the rest API would be good as well.

Comment: Thank you for checking it out! I've just updated the repo with created test case.

Comment: Thank, I gave it a look and I think it might be a bug. I need to create a simpler test case (one that only uses Hibernate Reactive) to make sure of it.

Comment: OK, I've forked a project and made some changes. Now it seems to work: https://github.com/DavideD/ogram-interviews/commits/master

Comment: I've sent a pr to your repository with the fixes that should make everything work. Ultimately, I think the answer to your question was correct, but there are some other things to fix in the project

Comment: Hello Davide, I can't thank you enough for making the fixes and comments. I will definitely check out the links you've provided on the matter. For some reason now when persisting an answer it fails with the error (tests are fine though): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`interviews`.`answer`, CONSTRAINT `FK8frr4bcabmmeyyu60qt7iiblo` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)". I'm trying to figure out why

Comment: I'm not sure about this but It usually depends on the order you are deleting entities. I would try to remove the related association before deleting the entity involved. It's probably better to ask these kind of questions on the Hibernate user topic on Zulip: https://hibernate.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/132096-hibernate-user

Comment: I've tried different ways, but still have this issue with fetching (one-to-many case, many-to-many works fine). I've created much smaller and simpler demo, if you still have time (and patience...) please have a look:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74391462/how-to-fetch-lazy-associations-in-hibernate-reactive

Comment: Mmmh... I've started to have a look at it and I don't see anything wrong. I don't know why you have the lazy initialization error. I can't see any mistake. I will have to create a project without kotlin and check if the same error happens again.

Comment: If I were you, I would create an issue at https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues - I don't think SO is suited for these kind of issues